# Does removing/re-installing my browser will remove old certificate store?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, certificate, certificate-authority, trusted-root-ca

I suspect that there is a malicious certificate added in my browser's certificate store. I mean Certificate Authority certificate.

How can I remove it in Chrome and Firefox?

If I remove my current browsers, then re-install them, will the old certificate store get removed?

Comment: Chrome uses the certificate store that exists on  the operating system.  Firefox uses it's own certificate store, manually removing the malicious certificate yourself, is the best way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Ramhound mentioned, Chrome works off Windows' certificate store, so here is a guide on [how to look for potentially malicious certificates](https://www.howtogeek.com/238765/how-to-check-for-dangerous-root-certificates-on-your-windows-pc/) installed on Windows. This mainly involves downloading [Sigcheck](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx) from the Sysinternals suite and running it.

> Type the following command at the command prompt and press Enter: `sigcheck -tv` Sigcheck will download a list of trusted certificates from Microsoft and compare it to the certificates installed on your computer. If there are any certificates on your computer that aren’t on the “Microsoft Certificate Trust List”, you’ll see them listed here. If everything is good and you don’t have any rogue certificates, you’ll see the “No certificates found” message.

Firefox does indeed have its own store, and it's tied to the profile, so there's no need to uninstall. You just need a fresh profile if you want to reset it. Alternatively, below is how you can find the certificates to review manually.

[image: Firefox Certificate store]